# Spring MVC : List<E> need to pass as command object

Tags: list, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to pass List as commandObject.

**My code**

```
public class Employee 
{       
List<Dept> dlist = new ArrayList<Dept>();    
public List<Dept> getDlist()
    {
return dlist;
}    
public void setDlist(List<Dept> dlList)
    {
this.dlist = dlist;
}       
}
```

**My jsp page**

```
<c:forEach var="d" items="${dlist}">
<spring:bind path="dlist[0].projectId">
<input type="text" name="projectId" value='<c:out value="${d.projectId}" />' />
</spring:bind>
</c:forEach>
```

But it not passing, where i making mistake, can any suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your forEach loop is broken you should iterate over the elements in your List of the command Object.

Use *form tags* instead of *spring:bind tags*

Try like this

```
<c:forEach var="d" items="${command.dlist}" varStatus="status">
  <form:input path="dlist[status.index].projectId" />
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 2):

You will have to wrap the list in a class, which it looks like you have done with Employee ?

It should look something like this then :

```
<form:form id="frmEmployee" commandName="myEmployee" action="/Whatever/" method="POST">
    <c:forEach items="${myEmployee.dlist}" var="dept" varStatus="status"><tr>
      <tr><td>
        <form:input path="dlist[status.index].projectId" id="title"/>
```