# Mapping object which containing a list in request - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to wrap an object which contain some `String` and a `List` of another object as property from requst in spring mvc?

My classes are :

```
public class MyObj {

private String ma;
private String mb;
private List<SecObj> mc;
}
```

and:

```
public class SecObj {

private String sa;
private String sb;
}
```

I want to get an object of `MyObj` from the request.

In my JSP

```
<form:form action="" method="POST" commandName="myObj"  >
<form:input  path="ma"  /> 
<form:input  path="mb"  /> 

.........
3 or 4 mc 
..........
</form:form>
```

If it is possible then

1. what should i write int `<form:input  path="?" />` **path?**
2. how i receive it in the request parameter `@RequestParam` ?

If it not possible at once then

**please tell me an good way to wrap this type of one to many relationship from request parameter**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the list, take a look at this issue: [Spring MVC : List<E> need to pass as command object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925063/spring-mvc-liste-need-to-pass-as-command-object) . The example shows that you can then fill in each field of SecObj individually, assuming SecObj has a public default constructor.

You could also register a formatter for SecObj to allow Spring to silently convert a whole user input String to SecObj. See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#format-configuring-formatting-mvc for details.